# Whats the best solution to implement retry on Servicestack JsonServiceClient Get method?

Tags: c#, servicestack

In my project I'm using Servicestack to fetch data from specific URL, this procedure is configurable and I call the fetch data in separate thread, I want to implement retry if the Timeout error is raised. I created wrapper class on JsonServiceClient and implement retry there, but I want to know what's the best solution for this approach.

```
var _client = new JsonServiceClient { Timeout = timeout };
var counter = 0;
do
{
    try
    {
        result = _client.Get<TResponse>(url);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //Logging exception
    }
}
while (++counter < this.Retry);
```

Comment: See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekPollyWannaFluentlyExpressTransientExceptionHandlingPoliciesInNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks @abatishchev, Already I saw this APIs, it's really awesome, but can not use it in this case, cause I want to implement retry for specific situation and also different retry attempt number bases on condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I created wrapper class on JsonServiceClient and implement retry there, but I want to know what's the best solution for this approach.

I agree with your approach. Extending the `JsonServiceClient` and implementing your retry logic there is the best approach for reusability and maintainability, provided you have implemented something like below.

## Extend `JsonServiceClient`

Extend the `JsonServiceClient` so you can incorporate your own retry logic. Then it is easily reusable in your code without the use of `while` and counters each time you want to make a request.

If you see the [`JsonServiceClientBase.cs`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceClientBase.cs) code here, you will note that all the verb methods such as `Get<TResponse>` `Post<TResponse>` ... `Put` etc. all call through the `Send<TResponse>(object request)` method.

Therefore by overwriting this method, we can implement the retry functionality easily on all verbs, without changing it's usage.

```cs
public class MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry : JsonServiceClient
{

    public MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry()
    {
    }

    public MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry(int retryAttempts)
    {
        RetryAttempts = retryAttempts;
    }

    public MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry(string baseUri) : base(baseUri)
    {
    }

    public MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry(string syncReplyBaseUri, string asyncOneWayBaseUri) : base(syncReplyBaseUri, asyncOneWayBaseUri)
    {
    }


    // Retry attempts property
    public int RetryAttempts { get; set; }


    public override TResponse Send<TResponse> (string httpMethod, string relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, object request)
    {
        int attempts = RetryAttempts;

        while(true) 
        {
            attempts--;

            try {
                return base.Send<TResponse> (httpMethod, relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, request);
            } catch (WebServiceException webException) {

                // Throw the exception if the number of retries is 0 or we have made a bad request, or are unauthenticated
                if(attempts == 0 || webException.StatusCode == 400 || webException.StatusCode == 401)
                    throw;

            } catch (Exception exception) {

                // Throw the exception if the number of retries is 0
                if(attempts == 0) 
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage:

- Replace reference to `JsonServiceClient` with `MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry`
- Set the attempt count
- Use the client as normal. (Wrap in `try/catch` block to catch exceptions after retries exceeded)

```cs
var client = new MyJsonServiceClientWithRetry ("http://localhost:8080") {
    RetryAttempts = 3,
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)
};


try
{
    var myRequestDto = new MyRequest {
        Name = "John Smith"
    };

    // This request will be attempted 3 times (if there is an exception)
    var response = client.Get<MyResponse>(myRequestDto);

    // Do something with response ...

} catch(Exception ex) {
    // Exception thrown here after 3 attempts (or immediately if status code is 400 / 401)
}
```

## Notes:

I don't retry if a `WebServiceException` is thrown with status code 400 or 401, because it seems redundant to try this request again without changing it. Obviously you can customise this logic.

If the connection times out then the timeout error is thrown as a [`WebException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx). In case you want to handle this case specifically.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I guess needs a simple change. Should override Get method instead on Send.

Comment: @Peyman You're welcome. You don't need to override `Get` because the underlying `Get` method calls the `Send<TResponse>` method which you have overwritten. I added a small fix, because I had missed the parameters of the `Send` method. But the above code, should allow calling Get, Put, Post, Delete and Send, without overriding each verb method.